# Eclipse problem

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, I no longer have the function that would sort of auto complete my statement. Such as if I typed in "Integer." and then a list of available methods would show up and I would be able to pick it. How do you activate this function?

Answer (score 2):

Active your code assist option in Windows/Preferences/ and just type code assist..

Answer (score 0):

In your preferences, (Window->Preferences->Java->Editor-Content Assist) have you enabled "Auto activation"? If so, what is the delay set there? Also look into the Advanced section and see whether there are any proposals checked.

Answer (score 0):

window/preference, type content assist, click Java/Editor/Content Assist.then check the checkbox under Auto Activation in the bottom,right side of the preference window.and you may also set the Aoto Activation triggers.
hope it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

If it was before and just gone, then try to clean your project.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem after installing eclipse 4.2.2.

It looks like the Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced tab no longer has "Java Proposals (Task Focussed)" in version 4.2.2 of eclipse, which is the one I previously had checked.

Version 4.2.2 does have a "Java Proposals" checkbox (unchecked in my fresh installation, using a previous workspace), checking that box restores the auto completion popup.